# Amazon EC2 instance and Elastic IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I have a running EC2 instance and one Elastic IP address allocated to it. Now I want to create a new instance for a demo project that will be using Elastic Beanstalk.

Question:

1. If I create one more new Elastic IP address for the newly created instance, will there be a charge to it?
2. If there is a charge, can I use the same elastic ip address for the newly created instance while running the current instance? If possible will there be a charge to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You will be charged for the new elastic IP until the IP is attached to a **running** instance - approximately $0.005/hour
2. Since the elastic IP is unattached between the time it was allocated and it was attached to a running instance, you'll be charged for at least one hour which is half a cent - $0.005/hour

From [Elastic IP Charges](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/)

An Elastic IP address doesn’t incur charges as long as the following conditions are true:

- The Elastic IP address is associated with an Amazon EC2 instance.
- The instance associated with the Elastic IP address is running.
- The instance has only one Elastic IP address attached to it.

Comment: So does it means that for the first qns there will be no charges to it? @helloV

Comment: okay, so if i create a new instance, create and assign a new ip address for it and provided that i have my current instance and the newly created instance both running, i won't be charged? Even though i have 2 elastic ip address create in my account?

Comment: Yes, you will be charged for one hour only . See my update.